# Loading remote Javascript file in Google Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am new to developing google chrome extension and I have a problem that I hope someone can help me with.

I have developed a simple google chrome extension that injects a script tag (eg. ) into the DOM and loading an external JS.

I have tested it and it actually works.
However, when I send it for approval, Google keeps on rejecting without giving proper reason.

I suspect it could be because I am loading an external JS script.
Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: no. google are not going to let you load in an external js file which they can not monitor. you could change the external code to anything, even malicious without them knowing.

Comment: However, I had a previous version doing the same thing approved that is why I am finding this very weird.

Comment: maybe they've tightened their security?

Comment: Did you declare that script in the external resources section of your manifest file?

Comment: Daniel, I did not. Do i have to? Can you share with me how I can do that?

Comment: At an absolute minimum, is that external script served over HTTPS? If not, it's very insecure.

Comment: Yes. The remote srcript is served over HTTPS

Answer (score 0):

There could be a number of reasons for this. **You should check your email for a more detailed explanation from the Chrome Team.** You can reply to this rejection email with an explanation of your external file and what it does, however this does not guarantee it will pass inspection. On a similar note, if the external script file is not being served from the verified domain associated with the extension/application it may automatically fail.